# PrimeFaces auto filter as we type

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces and I need auto filter functionality in the drop down control.

My requirement is that as I start typing, the drop down list should be filtered to show only the items that match with the entered characters.

I am currently using AutoComplete control and as you can see in the image below, it does NOT do the filtering, but only highlights the entered characters in bold.  Is there any property of this control that will help me do this out of the box or do I have to implement it myself?  If so, how to do the same?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<p:autoComplete id="state" label="state" completeMethod="#{patientBean.listStates}" required="true" dropdown="true" forceSelection="TRUE"/>
```

**Or, is there any other control that will help me achieve this out of the box?**

By the way, I am not sure if the following property of AutoComplete control is relevant to this by any chance?  Snippet from the PrimeFaces documentation given below:

```
autocomplete null String Controls browser autocomplete behavior.
```

**UPDATE**
I am using:
JSF 2.1.6
PrimeFaces 4.0

**Code**
test.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Test</ui:insert></title>
</h:head>

<h:body>    
    <h:form id="createPatientForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel value="State*"></p:outputLabel>  
            <p:autoComplete id="state" label="State" completeMethod="#{stateBean.listStates}" required="true" dropdown="true" forceSelection="TRUE"/> 
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>       
</html>
```

**StateBean.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class StateBean {
    private String state;

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public List<String> listStates(String district) {
        List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
        cities.add("California");
        cities.add("New Jersey");
        cities.add("Texas");

        return cities;
    }
}
```

Comment: `"My requirement is that as I start typing, the drop down list should be filtered"` Isn't that the behavior of the autocomplete already? Also, what version of PF/jsf/etc are you using? I get the feeling that what you want is to limit the input of the user to a specific set.

Comment: Can you show us more than one line of code?

Comment: I am not sure why the down vote is.  Can you add the reason for the same so that I can post better written questions from next time?

Comment: @Mindwin, As you can see in the image I've attached, the auto complete does NOT filter to show only the sub set of potentially a long list of input values in the drop down.  A long list can be very annoying to the end user to deal with in scrolling up and down to select the value he/she wants.  I am using JSF 2.1.6 and PrimeFacces 4.0.

Comment: I can't see the images, never did on this site, really. SO regulars prefer a working example they can paste into their IDE in order to reproduce your issue and work out an answer. As for the downvotes, I believe its for the vagueness of the question, and the lack of a working example. We are really here to help, not to troll. read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: And I really want to give you a good answer before BalusC comes and sweeps away all the rep. :D .............. but you have to help me and yourself.

Comment: I've added code for everyone's reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout SelectOneMenuFilter.

http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2097

Answer (score 1):

I know that there is an accepted answer already but I still want to give an answer to the problem with "Autocomplete"-control! It is possible to solve the problem with it and I think the autocomplete-control in some cases is better than the "SelectOneMenuFilter".

You just need to change your "listStates" method to do what you want! Right now your code did exactly what you told him to do! It created a list and put it into your autocomplete-control.

To get your desired result you need to change it accordingly like this:

```
public List<String> listStates(String district) {
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();
    cities.add("California");
    cities.add("New Jersey");
    cities.add("Texas");

    for (String value : cities) {
        if (value.toLowerCase().contains(district.toLowerCase())) {
            tempList.add(value);
        }
    }

    return tempList;
}
```